# 8051 open-drain operation

Tags: microcontroller, homework, 8051

While studying I found this question:

Write the value (in hex) of the P1 after the execution of the code below.

[image: Circuit]

```
unsigned char var; 
P1 = 0xff; 
var = P1; 
var = ~var; 
P1 = var; 
P1_0 = 1;
P1_4 = 0;
```

Consider P1 as open-drain with weak pull-ups.

I tried to answer the question, but I'm not sure of my answer. Can anyone help me?

My approach to solve the question:

First I analyzed the code and I saw that the P1 output would be 0x01, and then I analyzed the hardware.

P1.0 is High.
P1.1 is Low.
P1.2 is High.
P1.3 is High.
P1.4 is Low
P1.5 is High
P1.6 is Low
P1.7 is Low.

It would lead to a output of  0x2D (0b0010 1101).

My doubt is: In the code P1.0 is set to 1, and in the hardware it is connected to 1 (High). I believe that P1.0 is going to be 1. Therefore the answer is 0x2D.

But what if we have something like, by code PX is set to 1, but it's hard-wired to GND. I learned that open-drain port configuration work as a di-directional port, working as an output and an input, but I don't get what happens when there is a mismatch (trying to set a output, where there is an input).

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: What about the `var = ~var;` statement?

Comment: Everything will be set to 0, and in the final the only bit set to 1 is P1_0.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to consider the 8051's internal output transistor as a switch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4rGbl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It becomes pretty clear what potentials you should expect at P, with that switch in either open (M1 off) or closed (M1 on) state.

With pull *down* resistors, the system becomes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2TMly.png)</sup>

With no current path from a higher potential, node P is unable to go high, and both states result in \$V_P=0V\$. The only way that the 8051 could bring P high is by configuring its output to be push-pull, rather than open-drain.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that "open-drain" means that if you write a 0 to a pin, it will be forced to zero, but if you write a 1, then the pin will take on whatever state is determined by the external connection. The combination of the two for each pin is what you get when you read the port.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking for the internal circuit of the open-drain configuration and it make sense now.